# how to change font color and size within single label component in flex

Tags: apache-flex, label-control

i'm trying to create a unordered list in Flex.  My issue is that within each line, i want the word NEW to be a different font color and different font size from the rest of the label text.  I am unsure of how to do this INLINE within the label component.  Any thoughts anyone?

```
<s:VGroup fontSize="15" color="#ffffff">
    <s:Label text="\u2022 NEW Invite your friends!" />
    <s:Label text="\u2022 NEW Features coming soon!" />
    <s:Label text="\u2022 NEW Invite your friends!" />
</s:VGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flex3 you would just make a HBox with to Label containers that have different styles. Probably the same could be done in Flex 4 by making a Horizontal group within the vertical one you have.

Comment: thanks ladislav, actually ended up using a HTML within flex with <mx:Text><mx:htmlText>.....  and using <li> within the tag.  thanks for the help!